# How do I retrieve the SID of a signed in remote user in my domain and assign to a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sid

I think the title sums it up.

I typically use

```
gwmi win32_userprofile | select sid, localpath
```

So I can query the full list of users on a machine, but I am trying to streamline a process for remote computers.  I basically want to enter a computer name, then it will check for the currently logged in user, use that user account to find the associated SID.  From there I would want the SID assigned to a variable so I can use it for other functions in my script.

Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `UserName` property in the `Win32_ComputerSystem` WMI-class to get the currently logged on user and then convert the result. I use a `Foreach-Object`-loop so it will continue if there is a value (user logged in), but stop without error if the value was blank (no user logged in). Ex:

```
$currentusersid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username |
ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value }

PS C:\Users\frode> $currentusersid
S-1-5-21-333330555-1449773115-1111222333-1001
```

Comment: That's awesome thank you. So that code is more intended for a local machine correct?  Or can I use something like [Environment]::UserName to get the remote username?  Sorry I sound like a total beginner.  My background is in C++ so all the powershell stuff is foreign to me.

Comment: If you need to check a remote computer, try adding `-ComputerName "myremotecomputer"` parameter in the `Get-WmiObject` command

Comment: I will give that a shot.  Thank you so much for your help.  I'll upvote your response.

Comment: So would it look like my response below?

Comment: $currentusersid = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName xxxxxx12334|
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username |
    ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value }

Comment: @madwheel that is correct. also, instead of `[Environment]::UserName` you could use `$env:USERNAME`

Comment: @madwheel yes you could try that. @AnthonyStringer to use environment-variables he would need to use something like `invoke-command` to execute the code on the remote computer. With WMI he could run this from a management server :)

Answer (score 0):

to convert SID to user name

```
([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]('PUT-SID-HERE')).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

to convert user name to SID

```
([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]("domain\john.smith")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
```

and you could also use PsLoggedon.exe to get the logged in user name